# Optimize the very slow following code in C#

Tags: asp.net, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using ASPX.NET MVC4. I want to bring some data from the database, through a model, which I want to display as points at a chart at the view. At the chart I want to display at maximum 70 datapoints (date, value), but not more.

My model StudentGrades is consisted by the following

```
StudentID, ModuleID, TestDate, TestGrade.
```

I have written the following code, which does actually the job, but is **really** slow, and the time it needs is not acceptable.

Do you know how I can really optimize my code, (by changing the query, the datastructures, the loops, or anything other)?

My code is shown below.

```
var query = (from b in db.StudentGrades
                         where b.StudentID.Equals(InputStudentID)
                         orderby b.Date
                         select b);

            var dates = query.Select(x => EntityFunctions.DiffDays(query.Min(y => y.Date), x.Date));
            var grades = query.Select(x => x.grades);
            var datestable = dates.ToArray();
            var gradetable = grades.ToArray();
            List<int?> dateslist = new List<int?>();
            List<double> gradelist = new List<double>();
            double result = dates.Count() * 1.0 / 70.0;
            int pointStep = (int)Math.Ceiling(result);
            for (int i = 0; i < dates.Count(); i = i + pointStep)
            {
                dateslist.Add(datestable.ElementAt(i));
                gradelist.Add(gradetable.ElementAt(i));
            }
            ViewBag.dates = dateslist;
            ViewBag.grades = gradelist;
```

Thanks a lot

**EDIT**

I forgot to mention. I don't just want 70 points. I could then just do a take(70). What I actually want is those 70 points to be taken uniformly from my data, based at their dates. So if for example I have the following records at my database for a specific student, and instead of 70 points I wanted 3:

```
ModuleID, TestDate, TestGrade
23, 1 January 2014, 5
34, 2 January 2014, 54
45, 3 January 2014, 35
56, 4 January 2014, 55
67, 5 January 2014, 35
78, 6 January 2014, 56
89, 7 January 2014, 53
90, 8 January 2014, 55
94, 9 January 2014, 57
```

I would choose the record for 1 January 2014, 4 January 2014 and 7 January 2014 or something very similar. I mean the records I want should have equal, or relatively equal distance (in dates) between them.

This is also the reason why I have the pointStep variable above.

***Edit 2***

In addition, can you come up with a really clever way for this to be done in the query (without adding an id, as that changes my model)? If not, that's ok, I cannot do it either.

Thanks a lot

Comment: You should profile it using VS tools, or at minimum a `Stopwatch`. In general--since your end result is a small set of data points meant for a chart--I would do as much work in the database as possible and deal with aggregated/limited values in your model.

Comment: @TimMedora thanks a lot! Yes, actually transfer as much work as possible at the database, is what I want. But the problem is how?

Comment: You can use a SQL profiler trace to see the quer(ies) that are currently being submitted to the database by your code. It will show you the actual SQL statements and also the execution times. It may give you a starting point for your own stored procedure. The stored procedure should select/aggregate the data you need. Once you are happy with the results, call the stored procedure with ADO.Net and return a `DataReader` or `DataTable`.

Comment: When sampling that 70 rows, you are using `dates.Count()`, which does a database lookup at that point - that's 71 calls to the database for the same value. Change all of them to the `datestable` you already have in memory or even better: store that count once in a plain variable and use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First do one query to get the minimum date and store it in `minDate`.

Then you can do:

```
var query  = from b in db.StudentGrades
             where b.StudentID == InputStudentID
             orderby b.Date
             select x => new { Day = EntityFunctions.DiffDays(minDate, x.Date),
                               Grade = x.grades
                             }
```

Then get the records where `Day` is a multiple of `pointStep`:

```
var results = query.Where(x => x.Day % pointStep == 0).ToList();
var dateslist = results.Select(x => x.Day).ToList();
var gradelist = results.Select(x => x.Grade).ToList();
```

Now you will fetch only the required data from the database, and nothing more, in one query (well, two, frankly). Building the final lists happens in the blink of an eye.

Comment: Thanks a lot man! I will try it in a few hours. However, it seems really promising and thus you got my upvote. :)

Answer (score 1):

The term `query.Min(y => y.Date)` is executed for each row. Why don't you pull the minimum date once?

```
var minDate = query.Min(y => y.Date);
var dates = query.Select(x => EntityFunctions.DiffDays(minDate, x.Date));
```

Also, the query is executed for each of the following lines

```
var datestable = dates.ToArray();
var gradetable = grades.ToArray();
```

So your query is executed (N+3) times where N is the number of rows. This might happen in the server but is still quite a slow solution.

Solution: Put the `query` in an array at the very beginning to avoid multiple executions of the query.

```
var query = (from b in db.StudentGrades
                     where b.StudentID.Equals(InputStudentID)
                     orderby b.Date
                     select b).ToArray(); // <---- ToArray() does the trick.
```

But still you could clean up a bit by storing the minimum date once. This also makes the code a bit more readable. Try this:

```
var query = (from b in db.StudentGrades
                     where b.StudentID.Equals(InputStudentID)
                     orderby b.Date
                     select b).ToArray();
var minDate = query.Min(y => y.Date);
var dates = query.Select(x => EntityFunctions.DiffDays(minDate, x.Date));
// Nothing changed after this point
var grades = query.Select(x => x.grades);
...
```

Does this improve performance?

Comment: Hmmm... thanks a lot. I will try them in a few hours, because I have some courses now. They seem very helpful. Did you also came up with anything faster as regards the selection of the 70 points? I mean like this to be passed at query, or anything similar, which will be faster...

Answer (score 0):

ORMs like Entity Framework are great, but you need to pay *very* close attention to what you're doing or you'll end up hammering your database. The general rule to follow is that a query is only executed once the expression is evaluated. Things that will cause the expression to be evaluated are things like enumeration, casting to a list, array, etc., requesting a count, and so on. Basically, anything that will require *real data* will cause an evaluation.

That said, you also need to pay attention to order of operations. Issuing a `Select` before the expression is evaluated will *not* cause the expression to be evaluated: it merely adds to the query that will eventually be executed. On the other hand, if you issue a `Select` *after* the query is executed and as long as all the necessary data was pulled with that query, it will not require another query.

So, based on that, you can pretty much instantly improve the load time by causing an evaluation on your first line:

```
var query = (from b in db.StudentGrades
                     where b.StudentID.Equals(InputStudentID)
                     orderby b.Date
                     select b).ToList();
```

By casting to a list, the query will be executed immediately and the rest of your code will interact with that in-memory data. Whereas with your code as it is now, you'll issue one query for each line where you cast to an array, and another query when you later request the count.

Now, while your code is hardly efficient, I'm not seeing anything that should take any significant amount of time, even with issuing a few unnecessary queries. Nevertheless, you still want to get rid of those inefficiencies. So, watch while I condense your code from 14 lines to 3:

```
var query = (from b in db.StudentGrades
                     where b.StudentID.Equals(InputStudentID)
                     orderby b.Date
                     select b).ToList();
ViewBag.dates = query.Select(x => EntityFunctions.DiffDays(query.Min(y => y.Date), x.Date)).Take(70);
ViewBag.grades = query.Select(x => x.grades).Take(70);
```

You had a *ton* of code there just to simply limit the result to 70 data points; for that, you can just use `Take` and call it a day. But, there's actually one final optimization you can add, and it might actually be the ticket, since, like I said earlier, you didn't have any really crazy database-taxing code there. Therefore, the slowness is very likely due to the sheer volume of rows in this table, and the fact that you're initially pulling everything in. So, move the `Take` call off the `ViewBag.dates` and `ViewBag.grades` lines and put it on the `query` instead, before `ToList`:

```
var query = (from b in db.StudentGrades
                     where b.StudentID.Equals(InputStudentID)
                     orderby b.Date
                     select b).Take(70).ToList();
ViewBag.dates = query.Select(x => EntityFunctions.DiffDays(query.Min(y => y.Date), x.Date));
ViewBag.grades = query.Select(x => x.grades);
```

There, now your query will pull in only the first 70 rows and will execute immediately. The two selects you do will manipulate in-memory data, instead of issuing additional queries.

Comment: Thanks a lot Chris. I forgot to mention that I do not just want 70 records, but 70 records which have equally distance in days between two consecutive points. I have explained that better at my answer